# Positioning Issue

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this issue that's not allowing me to absolutely position a footer. I place it and It appears with like 5px margin in IE a lot of margin in Firefox and perfectly in Chrome...I really don't know why this happens...here's the HTML:

```
<p>In posuere dapibus mauris, et elementum magna rhoncus quis. Morbi ultricies malesuada magna, vel porta risus rhoncus a. Morbi aliquam facilisis dolor, scelerisque porttitor dui auctor id.</p> 
            </div><!-- /info -->
          </div><!-- /info-design -->
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div id="info-footer"></div><!-- /info-footer -->
        <div id="footer">

        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /wrapper -->
```

And the CSS:

```
#wrapper{font-size:1.2em;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width:100%;}

#content{margin:0 auto;width:1000px;}

#info-design{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -opera-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    opacity: .8;
    -moz-opacity: .8;
    -khtml-opacity: .8;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px double #000;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px 3px 3px 10px;
    width:985px;
    z-index:100;
}

#info{z-index:101;}

#info-footer{background:url(../img/BaseSite.gif) no-repeat center bottom;height:158px;position:absolute;bottom:0px;z-index:99;}

#footer{
    background:url('../img/cesped.jpg') repeat-x center bottom;
    height:176px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:98;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

I want the image "cesped.jpg" to appear just in bottom:0px; but it just won't stay there =/ did I missed something or added something I shouldn't have?

---

**Edit**

I basically want to make the footer be at the very bottom of "content" div but it can't be placed within that div because it's a fixed width and I want this image to go repeat-x to the whole browser (hence it's placed after content and before wrapper which has a width="100%"; I have tried making wrapper's position absolute and relative but still it won't place itself at the very bottom...and I have tried it to be pushed down "naturally" but it just won't...

Here's how it should look like (and looks like in Chrome): [image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3633/3694294045_9fcaca4d19_o.jpg))</sub>

and then here's IE and Firefox:

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2617/3694294651_e2b50e39d1_o.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3556/3694294403_4f8e3c1a40_o.jpg))</sub>

---

**Edit 2**

I found the issue, for some reason my #wrapper is not extending to cover the whole browser height but only a fraction of it, would anyone know what am I missing? I added:

```
#wrapper{font-size:1.2em;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width:100%;min-height:100%;}

#content{margin:0 auto;width:1000px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to place the footer in relation to... what? I guess "at the absolute bottom of `<div id="wrapper">`"? Then you need to make your wrapper either `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`. Absolutely positioned elements [orient themselves on the closest parent](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) that has a `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute` position. From your CSS that would seem to be the nothing but the `<html>` or `<body>`.

Also, both your `info-footer` and `footer` elements would be positioned at the very bottom layered on top of each other. Is that the desired effect?

Maybe you could post a mockup of what you want it to look like, and what it looks like now?

Is it really necessary to do it this way, instead of just having the content push the footer down "naturally"?

**EDIT**: Not sure if I understood it correctly, but what about simply `repeating` the background image along the bottom of `<body>`?

```
body { background: url(image.jpg) repeat-x center bottom; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to edit 2: `position:absolute` takes Elements out of the document flow, thus their heights will not be enforced on their parent (or, the parent won't grow to accommodate them). That's why adding a height will work; but, if your absolutely positioned Elements wind up being taller than that height that you set, the same thing will happen.

In the above, it looks like `div#info-design` doesn't need to be positioned absolutely at all (from what I can tell). You could remove that declaration, give it a `margin-bottom` equal to the height of `div#footer` and achieve the same effect without relying on setting an arbitrary height on `div#wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding margin-bottom: 50px to your #wrapper work?